# Pagination with filtering using CursorLoader, AutocompleteTextView, CursorAdapter, ContentProvider in android

Tags: android, pagination, filtering, android-cursorloader

I have some trouble when using `CursorLoader`... I want to download data from inet API page by page, however;

1. I also want to make pagination of the listview. It means that data should be downloaded page by page when the end of listview is reached.
2. I also want to filter my listview inputing constraint-text in `AutocompleteTextView`.

Each of these features works properly when I use them separately, but when I want use them together it works not pretty well. I want to implement such a scenario: if I entered filter-text in `AutocompleteTextView` my listview was invalidated (that works fine) and downloading process would start until listview size reach the end of screen.

The problem is I don't know how to organize the cursor update through `CursorLoader`, when I should restart loader and when should't I?  Should I restart loader only when I set filter (setFilterQueryProvider, method  runQuery(CharSequence constraint)) or should I do it when give new portion of data from inet?

Now when process was started I found out that callback onLoadFinished wasn't called and  listview wasn't updated...

Maybe anybody give me some working example...

Answer (score 0):

You could change your CursorLoader for an AsyncTaskLoader to fetch new information when no records found according to the filter criteria. With the AsyncTaskLoader you could handle DB and UI operations to manage the Activity's state when it is downloading data or querying it locally.

Hope it helps.